# Adding character values of a column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two columns i.e. square_id & Smart_Nsmart as given below.
I want to count(add) N's and S's against each square_id and ggplot the data i.e. plot square_id vs Smart_Nsmart.

**square_id** 1 
1
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 
**Smart_Nsmart**
S N N N S S N S S S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `count` and then use `ggplot` to plot the frequency.  Here, we are plotting it with `geom_bar` (as it is not clear from the OP's post)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
   count(square_id, Smart_Nsmart) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x= square_id, y = n, fill = Smart_Nsmart)) + 
         geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: What if i want to reorder below code against say top 50, what should be added in code.
totalHandsetActivity=inputSubsetDF %>% 
  count(square_id, Smart_Nsmart)
  totalHandsetActivity %>% ggplot(., aes(x= square_id, y = n, fill = Smart_Nsmart)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

Comment: @MuhammadMurtaza  You can try `df %>% count(square_id, Smart_Nsmart) %>% top_n(n, 50) %>% ggplot(., `

Comment: Error: `n` must be a scalar integer

Comment: @MuhammadMurtaza  It is  because of a conflict there as the `count` returns 'n' as column name and `top_n` has an argument `n`.  So you can use `df %>% count(square_id, Smart_Nsmart) %>% top_n(wt = n, 50)`

Comment: Checked with following code, showing plot but not ordering in Ascending/Descending order.
  totalHandsetActivity=inputSubsetDF %>%
  count(square_id, Smart_Nsmart) %>% top_n(wt = n, 50)
  totalHandsetActivity %>%ggplot(., aes(x= square_id, y = n, fill = Smart_Nsmart)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

Comment: @MuhammadMurtaza  Try `df %>% count(square_id, Smart_Nsmart) %>% top_n(wt = n, 50) %>%  arrange(desc(n)) %>% mutate_at(1:2, funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% ggplot(., aes(x= square_id, y = n, fill = Smart_Nsmart)) +   geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: Also add `arrange(desc(n))` after the `top_n` and then convert to `factor`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is very smart. However, instead of `count` function, you can implement `group_by` and `summarise` just in case in future you want to apply some other functions to your code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dff <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,2,1,2),b=c("C","C","N","N","N","C","N"))

dff %>% 
group_by(a,b) %>% 
summarise(n = length(b) ) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x= a, y = n, fill = b)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```